# Extend an existing Views filter (NumericFilter) throws exception

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to do something that should be easy in Views but I can't seem to be able to make it work.

I need to create a filter on top of the existing `NumericFilter` (`Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\NumericFilter`), but with a minimalistic approach like the following it is simply not working.

```
<?php
// @file src/Plugin/views/filter/FoobarProjectSizeRangeSelectionFilter.php

namespace Drupal\foobar_extra\Plugin\views\filter;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\NumericFilter;
/**
 * Class DateYearFilter
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 * @ViewsFilter("project_size_range_select")
 */
class FoobarProjectSizeRangeSelectionFilter extends NumericFilter {
}
```

The way I use is is pretty straight forward:

```
<?php
// @file foobar.views.php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function foobar_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  // clone an existing field
  $data['node__field_a']['field_a_value_range'] = $data['node__field_a']['field_a_value'];
  // change name and filter ID
  $data['node__field_a']['field_a_value_range']['title'] = t("Foobar");
  $data['node__field_a']['field_a_value_range']['filter']['id'] = 'project_size_range_select';

  return $data;
}
```

Whenever I try to save a view using this filter plugin i get the following error:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException:
>  The configuration property display.default.display_options.filters.field_a_value_range.value.min doesn't exist.
>  in Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get()
>  (line 74 of ROOT/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php).
> ```

Right now I have "worked around it" implementing some custom and terrible hacks, but i'm pretty sure this is so simple that it should just work.

Answer (score 10):

So, yeah I ended up investigating more and more and I needed to specify a config schema definition as it follows.

```
# @file config/schema/foobar.views.schema.yml
#
# Schema for the views plugins.

views.filter.project_size_range_select:
  type: views_filter
  label: 'Foobar numeric'

views.filter_value.project_size_range_select:
  type: views.filter_value.numeric
  label: 'Foobar Numeric'
```

The full gist is [available here if anyone is interested.](https://gist.github.com/esolitos/dba880ba0a71d19f8d39c6dd37f0bbdc)